# `enable_if()` to disable static member function declaration of templated class

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to declare function in template class so that function declaration depends on a template type argument.

```
template<typename T>
struct Block
{
    static bool parse(int32_t index, 
                      const typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type& value);

    static bool parse(int32_t index, 
                      typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type value);
....

};
```

So I want to have, say, `Block<uint16_t>` and `Block<std::string>` and `parse()` is declared as:

```
bool parse(int32_t index, const std::string& value);
or
bool parse(int32_t index, uint16_t value);
```

But I'm getting error: `'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
  ...typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<T>::value, T>::type value);`

Could you help me to properly declare functions?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable_if only works in deduced contexts.   In your example, the deduction is done at class type time.  By the time you get to the functions, T is already known, so there isn't anything to deduce.

You can make an otherwise superfluous template parameter, set its default type to T and then deduce on that.

```
template<typename T>
struct Block
{
    // now parse has to deduce U
    template<typename U=T>
    static bool parse(int32_t index, 
                      typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<U>::value, T>::type value);
```

Your callers will never know that `parse` actually has a template parameter, but now you can do all the fancy stuff on it.

Comment: noup, getting `out-of-line definition...`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/yrjX19QW3wjaGPxX

Comment: If you put the function definition inline, it works fine. 
 https://wandbox.org/permlink/XgzDCmKle33DuNvP . The way you are trying to define them outside the class is wrong.  The signatures don't line up.

Comment: That's the problem I want to keep definitions outside. I have a few different classes with different parsers but same parameter type. Like: `using BlockS1 = Block<std::string>; using BlockS2 = Block<std::string>`. This block actually has an additional `typename`s to distinguish BlockS1 from BlockS2 but parser is based on first parameter only. That's why I'm up to specialisation of parser functions. Sorry, I tried to make example as simple as possible and removed everything else. I updated example to make it more clear https://wandbox.org/permlink/aep3akqdtrkpxAju

Comment: @user3124812 I would just specialize the class instead of parse.

Answer (score 1):

1. An alternative solution without SFINAE is to use tag dispatch:

   ```
   template<typename S>
   static bool parse(int32_t index, S&& value) {
       return parse_impl(index, value, std::is_class<T>{});
   }

   private: 
   static bool parse_impl(int32_t index, const T& value, std::true_type);
   static bool parse_impl(int32_t index, T value, std::false_type);
   ```

   Note that in this solution, `parse()` accepts any type `S`, and if `S` is not convertible into `T`, the fail will occur inside `parse()` itself. This can be too late, if `parse()` itself is used for SFINAE. For example, the following template:

   ```
   template<class S, class T, typename = decltype(S::parse(0, std::declval<T>()))>
   ```

   will result in a soft-fail (which is not an error) for the original `parse()` and in a hard-fail (which is a compile error) for the proposed tag-dispatched version. Thanks **xaxxon** for point out this difference.
2. In C++20 with concepts, `requires` will simplify things:

   ```
   static bool parse(int32_t index, const T& value)
   requires std::is_class_v<T>
   { ... }

   static bool parse(int32_t index, T value)
   requires !std::is_class_v<T>
   { ... }
   ```

Comment: Your function takes an S and then calls a function that wants a T.

Comment: @xaxxon, and what is the problem with that?

Comment: Because that will fail too late in the process for other things to potentially rely on whether parse is valid to call with some other type T.   Why would you change the prototype of parse from what the question specifies it needs to be?

Comment: @xaxxon, if `parse()` has to fail early, then yes, it's a good point. I'll make a note in the answer.

Comment: @xaxxon, I've updated my answer. I hope I got right what you meant by "too late".

Comment: @xaxxon, then you'll not be able to pass lvalue references: https://godbolt.org/z/csRqWq

Comment: Then verify S is convertible to T with sfinae: https://godbolt.org/z/wvmW8w